# run OS command inside a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, wget, python-os

I have a script where I first create a folder (named after i, the list element in the for loop). Then I want to go inside the created folder using `cd` and run the wget command inside it.

However, currently, the wget command runs in the root folder and downloads all files over there (instead of navigating into the folder and then downloading files inside it)

Maybe I have to put a timer or wait before the folders are created? How can I fix this and **run the wget command inside the created folder**?

```
import os
lst = ['www.sr-line.com','www.montratec.com']

for i in lst:
    print(i)
    os.system('mkdir %s' % i)
    os.system('cd %s' % i)
    #os.system('mkdir test')
    os.system('wget -A pdf -m -p -E -k -K -nd %s' % i)
    os.system('cd ..')
```

Comment: What's your problem while doing these things? I didn't understand what's you problem or you didn't mentioned it clearly!

Comment: I want to go inside a folder and then run this ```os.system('wget -A pdf -m -p -E -k -K -nd %s' % i)``` inside that folder, then return back to the home folder. Currently, it just runs the wget command and downloads file in the home folder where the script is located. Does that make sense now? @Kshitiz

Comment: `os.system("cd test ; wget ...")`

Comment: Can you help me with the syntax since I am using % I for strings? This gives me a syntax error currently ```os.system('mkdir %s' % i; 'cd %s' % i; 'wget -A pdf -m -p -E -k -K -nd %s' % i; 'cd ..')``` @furas

Comment: you have to put all commands in one string with `;` inside this string - and use only one `%` after this string - likes `"string" % (i, i, i)` OR you should use `f-string` or `.format()`

Answer (score 2):

Each command is executed in a new shell, you need to chain them together:

```
import os
lst = ['www.sr-line.com', 'www.montratec.com']

for i in lst:
    command = f'mkdir -p /tmp/{i}; cd /tmp/{i}; wget -A pdf -m -p -E -k -K -nd {i}'
    os.system(command)
```

Comment: is it necessary to add tmp?

Comment: No. I prefer to use full path's to know where things saved ... depends on how you execute the script have a look at my answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68161261/reading-a-file-no-such-file-or-directory/68161726#68161726)

Comment: No, I don't think you have to add `/temp/{i}` you can just do `/{i}` only.

Comment: Also, what is fll?

Comment: @x89: Typo, fixed that :)

Comment: ```mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/{i}’: Permission denied
sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /{i}``` @Kshitiz I would get this if I do just /{i}

Comment: We are not trying to making directory while just doing `{i}` we are saving file in the same directory where we are now! But anyway my mistake that I mentioned `/{i}` rather then `{i}`

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you could use direct Python operations and not start a shell for each command. This could give more readable and faster code. For example (see [documentation of Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) for details), on Linux (untested code):

```
 os.mkdir(i)
 oldwd = os.getcwd()
 os.chdir(i)
 os.system('wget -A pdf -m -p -E -k -K -nd %s' % i)
 os.chdir(oldwd)
```

And you don't even need to fork a `wget` command (that program might not even be installed)... You could use facilities from [os.urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html)

Remember that starting a new process is a quite costly operation (and your OS could fail on that: on Linux see [fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)...)

Comment: For now, it gives me ```SyntaxError: invalid syntax``` at ```var oldwd```

Comment: Remove the `var`

Answer (score 1):

You can run put many commands in one string separated by `;`.

```
os.system("mkdir test ; cd test ; wget ...")
```

If comands need to use parameters then you should use only one `%` with list/tuples of all values

```
os.system('mkdir %s ; cd %s ; wget -A pdf -m -p -E -k -K -nd %s ; cd ..' % (i, i, i) )
```

Or you should use `.format()`

```
os.system('mkdir {} ; cd {} ; wget -A pdf -m -p -E -k -K -nd {} ; cd ..'.format(i, i, i))
```

but simpler would be use `f-string`

```
os.system(f'mkdir {i} ; cd {i} ; wget -A pdf -m -p -E -k -K -nd {i} ; cd ..')
```

---

**EDIT:**

Eventually you can create every command separatelly and later concatenate them - it can be simpler with list

```
all_cmds = [
   'mkdir %s' % i,
   'cd %s' % i,
   'wget -A pdf -m -p -E -k -K -nd %s' % i,
   'cd ..'
]

cmd = ';'.join(all_cmds)
```

It can be usefull if you want to use `if/else` to skip some elements

```
create_subfolder = True # False

all_cmds = []

if create_subfolder:
   all_cmds.append( 'mkdir %s' % i )
   all_cmds.append( 'cd %s' % i )

all_cmds.append( 'wget -A pdf -m -p -E -k -K -nd %s' % i )

if create_subfolder:
   all_cmds.append( 'cd ..' )

cmd = ';'.join(all_cmds)
```

**BTW:**

This method can be useful also to add or skip parameters in single command

```
cmd = ['wget']

if some_parameter:
    #cmd.append('-A pdf')
    #cmd.extend(['-A', 'pdf']) 
    cmd += ['-A', 'pdf'] 

cmd += ['-m', '-p', '-E', '-k', '-K', '-nd', i] # directly `i` without `%s`

cmd = ' '.join(cmd)  # join with spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

Running `system()` will start a new process. What that process does, does not affect the parent process, so a directory change there doesn't affect any other process elsewhere, including a sibling process started by the same parent.

Just tell `wget` where to store things or perform the dir change in a process that affects `wget`, like e.g. a parent.

Comment: Could you help me with how to formulate the command? ```os.system('mkdir %s' % i; 'cd %s' % i; 'wget -A pdf -m -p -E -k -K -nd %s' % i; 'cd ..')``` This gives me a syntax error for now

Comment: It's not about the command, your string formatting is off. Keep in mind that both Python and the shell code you're generating uses quotes. Start small and then extend.